# Minimum norm solution of a least squares using SVD

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be any real matrices. I would like to find the solution of a linear system $Ax=B$ using the SVD decomposition of $A$ given by $A = U S V^t$. If I am not very wrong, I believe I can obtain this solution using

$\ \ \ X = VL^tU^tB$

in which

$\ \ \
  L_{ij} =
  \begin{cases}
      1/S_{ij} && \text{if} S_{ij} \not= 0 \\\\
      0        && \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
$

This seems to work. However, for the case when $A$ has more columns than rows, I would like to find not only the best solution (in the least squares sense), but also the solution which has minimum norm. How can I do that?

$\\\\$

For example, by taking

$
\ \ \ A = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\\\
  4 & 5 & 6 
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ 
B = \begin{pmatrix}
   7 &  8 &  9 \\\\
  10 & 11 & 12 
\end{pmatrix}
$

The aforementioned method gives the solution

$\ \ \ \hat{X} = \begin{pmatrix}
   -2.1667 &  -2.6667 & -3.1667 \\\\
    0.3333 &   0.3333 &  0.3333 \\\\
    2.8333 &   3.3333 &  3.8333 \\\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

I can verify this is a valid solution by taking

$\ \ \ A\hat{X} = \begin{pmatrix}
   7 &  8 &  9 \\\\
  10 & 11 & 12 
\end{pmatrix}$

However, I am not sure this is the minimum norm solution.

Comment: You're missing a transpose in $X = VL^tU^tB$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. By the way, I just realized I should have asked this on math.stackexchange instead. Didn't realized there was a different site for more trivial questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the wikipedia page on the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Minimum-norm_solution_to_a_linear_system), specifically Sections 5.3, 6.1, and 6.3.

Comment: So it seems the solution I mentioned is indeed the least squares solution then. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. ----